# Remove quotes from string so I can add it to a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, refactoring

While refactoring my dashboard controller, I have broken the parts related to each of the different user polymorphic types into their own model.

For example, I use

```
Dashboard::Teacher.new(current_user)
```

for teachers,

```
Dashboard::Student.new(current_user)
```

for students, and

```
Dashboard::Parent.new(current_user)
```

for parents.

To remove duplicate code, how would I set the polymorphic user type which is a string into:

```
Dashboard::#{UserTypeGoesHere}.new(current_user)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Module#const_get` to access a class defined within a module, based on its string value:

```
user_type = "Parent"
Dashboard.const_get(user_type).new(current_user)
```

In the above code `Dashboard.const_get(user_type)` simply evaluates to `Dashboard::Parent`:

```
Dashboard.const_get("Parent") == Dashboard::Parent  # => true
```

Comment: Seems to cause a undefined method `stringify_keys' error now.

Comment: `stringify_keys` is a method defined on the Hash object by ActiveSupport in Rails, not sure what it would have to  do with the above example. Can you post the code that's causing the error?